# Yii - Can we use Form widgets functionality with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, yii

I am currently doing a portion of a project in jquerymobile for mobile users.

I want to know whether we can use the form widgets functionality wrapped up in jquerymobile. Because i could see the CSS of jquery mobile is not applied for text inputs. So i need whether this is the issue. so that i can change it now itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use simple input fields and submit form through jquery
>   ajax...it can work..

Comment: I created with simple input fields but naming conventions as yii functionality. eg. name =$modelname["dbfieldname"]. Doing this will make the life easy when coming to save part.